# broadcast test in karma using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have created an controller, i want to test that controller using karma but i tried to do broadcast test

**Controller:**

```
$scope.load = function() 
{        
    // Fetch the listing, .then()
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dateUpdate');
}
```

**unit testing**

```
it('should broadcast the fact that the listing was loaded', function() 
{
     spyOn(rootScope, '$broadcast');
     $scope.load();
     expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('dateApply');
});
```

but i got **error** like this

> Expected spy $broadcast to have been called with [ 'dateApply' ] but it
>   was never called
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating'c.$broadcast("$locationChangeStart",b,a,k.$$state,f).defaultPrevented')

Comment: Well, first of all, the code actually passes 'dateUpdate' as argument, not 'dateApply'. Second, show a **complete** test example. We have no idea how you initialized the scope, the root scope, etc.

Comment: ok i ll give plnkr example what i have tried.

Comment: There is no $scope.load() in the code you posted. It's also full of completely irrelevant stuff (your test alone has 1800 lines). Post, in the question itself, a minimal but complete example reproducing the problem

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TWYANHIjcSmzjdiaCS0G I have included the example plnkr url what i have tried..the file names are unittest.js and main.js.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, in my files have lot of coding so please provide any examples with link or tutorials for broadcast test for karma.. It ll help me lot.